# How to split a varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Our company recently changed our email address. Only the part after the `@` changed. For example, if your email was `name@oldEmail.com` it is now `name@newEmail.com`.

In our database, there is a column that stores all of emails. I need to convert all the old emails to the new emails.

I have this for my SQL:

```
update Contacts set EmailAddress1=() where EmailAddress1 like '%oldEmail.com%';
```

The `where` part should pull all the rows with the old email address, but I am not sure how to set them to the new one. I need to do some string manipulation. Is there a simple way to do this?

It is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: You don't want or need the `%` after `oldEmail.com`.

Comment: Does having it there allow for there to be characters after the `.com`?

Comment: That's what it does. From your description, you don't want that, you only want the leading `%`.

Comment: @user489041 why would there be characters are ".com"?  See Abe Miessler's answer, that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
update Contacts 
set EmailAddress1 = REPLACE(EmailAddress1,'@oldEmail.com','@newEmail.com') 
where EmailAddress1 like '%oldEmail.com';
```